# Remove element from session array in laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel, laravel-5

I am a newbie in Laravel 5 and trying to make an eCommerce web application by learning on my own.

I have the following array of products:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "productId" => 3
    "quantity" => 2
    "productName" => "Testing Product 3"
    "productRate" => 275.0
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "productId" => 2
    "quantity" => 2
    "productName" => "Testing Product 2"
    "productRate" => 180.0
  ]
]
```

Now when a user clicks on the `x` link which is in the view of the cart template, it does delete the product from the session, but it also removes the full array of session cart on the next page reload.

Here's the controller for deleting the product:

```
public function destroy($id) {

    if ( \Session::has( 'cart' ) && is_array( \Session::get('cart') ) ) {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
            
        for ($i=0; $i < count($cart); $i++) {
            foreach ($cart[$i] as $key => $value) {
                if ( $key === 'product' && $value == $id ) {
                    unset( $cart[$i] );
                }
            }
        }       
        return redirect('/cart')->with('cart', $cart);
    }
}
```

I also tried like this:

```
unset( $cart[$i][$key] )
```

But this gave me the `undefined index` error.

Kindly guide me where have I made mistake and what is the solution for it.

**UPDATE 1**:

Here's the index function:

```
public function index() {
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    return view('cart.index')->with('cart', $cart);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:
As per the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74915/discussion-between-mininoz-and-user3514160), Here's the destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id) {

    if ( \Session::has( 'cart' ) && is_array( \Session::get('cart') ) ) {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        
        foreach ($cart as $index => $product) {
            if ($product['productId'] == $id) {
                unset($cart[$index]);
            }
        }
        session(['cart' => $cart]);
        return redirect('/cart');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$id` ?  Is it `productId` or The `Array Index`?

Comment: it is the `productId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `foreach` instead of `for` to loop through the array. Because you might get an error if the array key is not start with `0` or there is any skip array key like `0,1,3`.

```
foreach ($cart as $index => $product) {
  if ($product['productId'] == $id) {
     unset($cart[$index]);
   }
}
session(['cart' => $cart]);
```

I just update the code to update the `$cart` value (after removed some product) back to the session.

**Update**
We do not need `with function` after `redirect function`

```
return redirect('/cart')->with('cart', $cart);
```

to

```
return redirect('/cart');
```

Comment: What will it do ? I tried your code, and what I got is: a page reload with the same session and then on next page load, no data in the session.

Comment: Did you un-comment `unset` line? I just updated my code.

Comment: Tried again, this time it worked, but on again page reload, the session disappeared. I mean there were no products at all.

Comment: which page did you reload?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the index action code (/cart)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74915/discussion-between-mininoz-and-user3514160).